# Issue with first Firebase query item out of order until refresh

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database to pull 50 users with the highest integer value and to display them from highest to lowest. The issue will arise when I enter the leaderboard view for the first time. The order should show jlewallen18 at the top AND THEN appledev. But on first load appledev is at the top, until I back out and open the leaderboard again (code at the bottom).

[image]

Leaderboard code:

```
class LeaderboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var leaderboardTableView: UITableView!

    var userModel : [User] = [User]()

    let pipeline = ImagePipeline {
    //config settings for image display removed for brevity
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        leaderboardTableView.delegate = self
        leaderboardTableView.dataSource = self

        fetchUsers()
    }

    func fetchUsers() {
        let queryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "ranking").queryLimited(toLast: 50)
        queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.userModel.append(user)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.leaderboardTableView.reloadData()
            })
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userModel.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leaderboardTableCell", for: indexPath) as! LeaderboardTableCell
        if userModel.count > indexPath.row {
            if let profileImageURL = userModel[indexPath.row].photoURL {
                let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)!
                var options = ImageLoadingOptions()
                options.pipeline = pipeline
                options.transition = .fadeIn(duration: 0.25)
                Nuke.loadImage(
                    with: ImageRequest(url: url).processed(with: _ProgressiveBlurImageProcessor()),
                    options: options,
                    into: cell.userImage
                )
            }
        }
        cell.userName.text = userModel[indexPath.row].username
        cell.watchTime.text = "\(String(describing: userModel[indexPath.row].watchTime!))"
        cell.ranking.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userImage.frame.size.width/2
        return cell
    }
}
```

I thought it might be because I am using the same model name `userModel` in both my Profile page view and my Leaderboard view but when i changed the model name in my leaderboard view nothing changed. What else can I share to help? Thanks!

EDIT: here's my console output after printing out `watchTime` which is the integer I have rankings for:

```
HERES WHERE I OPEN LEADERBOARD PAGE FIRST:
Optional(28)
Optional(247)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
AFTER I GO BACK AND CLICK TO VIEW LEADERBOARD AGAIN:
Optional(247)
Optional(28)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
Optional(0)
```

Comment: What happens if you set the array to empty before fetching users?

Comment: @CaseyWest good question, I tried adding `userModel.removeAll()` above the query in `fetchUsers()` but this unfortunately returned the same result

Comment: darn...and if you track the array of users it loads up the currentUser first and then appends according to the queryOrderedBy ref? I might need to look at your project to help more. Sorry man.

Comment: @CaseyWest yea, I added my console output in my original question. Weird because this exact code works perfectly on my home page

Comment: @CaseyWest so it is dependent on who is logged in. I switched from my appledev account to my jlewallen user account and it now orders jlewallen on top first on initial leadboard page load...hmm. It's like it's caching and displaying the logged in user first

Comment: Hmm..yeah somehow that UserModel has to be retaining the currentUser from the profile screen or something. It seems like you already tested that but I would test again and make sure you aren't passing any information from ProfileVC to the LeaderboardVC

Comment: @CaseyWest yea unfortunately double checked with no luck, only performing segue with no data passage. Are you comfortable with teamviewer to look at the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172625/discussion-between-casey-west-and-jordan-lewallen).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is related to this line of code...

```
let queryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "ranking").queryLimited(toLast: 50)
```

Changing this limit to 10 makes the app work as expected, which is a temporary 'fix'.

If we figure out why that limit is causing issues I'll be sure to update this answer.

Comment: marking as correct as this answers the original question. I'd like to add that this line was attempting to query 50 accounts when there were only 6.

Comment: @JordanLewallen just wondering if you ever got this working with more than 10?

Comment: never did :/ contacted Firebase support and they couldn’t replicate..real odd, seems to be project specific

Comment: @JordanLewallen why unaccept? Want me to look into it more?

Comment: odd, not sure why it unaccepted (maybe when I was on mobile responding to the recent message). However, I guess, yea, it shouldn't be marked as correct as it doesn't exactly fix the problem :/ I would LOVE if you could have another look at it, would you like the most recent build?

Comment: @JordanLewallen sure send me the build and I can take a look at it this week when I have a moment!